# parsing string datetimes in C3

Tags: javascript, c3.js

Does anyone know where to find documentation on how C3 is parsing datetime strings? It doesn't seem to match the format of moment.js, nor any clear documentation I can find. If I have a datetime string in the format `2013-01-01 04:23:56-05:00`, how can I account for that timezone (`-5:00`) at the end?

Answer (score 0):

C3 parse datetimes string using [D3 time formatting](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Time-Formatting.md) that is set in [xFormat config option](http://c3js.org/reference.html#data-xFormat).

You may need something like that:

```
data: {
  xFormat: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%Z'
}
```

where %Z refers to timezone.

Note than D3 timezone has format `-0500`, not `-05:00`.